# Not able to upload to S3 with paperclip rails 5. invalid configuration option :bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I've been struggling for some time now trying to configure paperclip to upload files into my S3 account.

And when I try to upload a file, the following error prompts.

> no member 'bucket' in struct
>
> invalid configuration option :bucket

Doing my own research and digging into the aws-sdk, I've found out that the aws-sdk works with a list of plugins and each plugin adds an specific set of configurable fields into a struct, this struct works as a check list and if the object tries to add an option that is not present, it raises an exception. For some reason the ":bucket" attribute is not added into that struct.

I am using aws-sdk (2.6.50) and paperclip (5.2.1) in rails 5.1.2

My configuration setup in application.rb is

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    s3_region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
    s3_host_name: ENV['S3_HOST_NAME']
  }
}
```

Here is a portion of the backtrace.

```
block in Seahorse::Client::Configuration#apply_options
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb, line 163
Seahorse::Client::Configuration#apply_options
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb, line 161
Seahorse::Client::Configuration#build!
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb, line 149
Aws::S3::Client#build_config
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb, line 68
Aws::S3::Client#initialize
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb, line 19
Aws::S3::Client.new
aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb, line 105
Aws::S3::Resource#extract_client
aws-sdk-resources (2.6.50) lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb, line 169
Aws::S3::Resource#initialize
aws-sdk-resources (2.6.50) lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb, line 15
Paperclip::Attachment#obtain_s3_instance_for
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb, line 269
Paperclip::Attachment#s3_interface
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb, line 263
Paperclip::Attachment#s3_bucket
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb, line 273
Paperclip::Attachment#s3_object
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb, line 281
Paperclip::Attachment#exists?
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb, line 326
block in Paperclip::Attachment#queue_all_for_delete
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb, line 569
Paperclip::Attachment#queue_all_for_delete
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb, line 568
Paperclip::Attachment#clear
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb, line 259
Paperclip::Attachment#assign
paperclip (5.2.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb, line 107
```

And this is the method where it fails.

aws-sdk-core (2.6.50) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb

```
  def apply_options(struct, options)
    options.each do |opt, value|
      begin
        struct[opt] = value
      rescue NameError
        msg = "invalid configuration option `#{opt.inspect}'"
        raise ArgumentError, msg
      end
    end
```

I have checked if the bucket name is set up correctly and it is.

I appreciate your help beforehand.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to put `s3_region` out side of credential block.

Comment: Look at the gist, there have full tutorial to `paperclip` and `s3` with Rails https://gist.github.com/belgoros/b289a0b57b52d16b99d436ca9b80417f

Comment: @fool-dev I was following that gist

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay That helped! that was not part of the problem but it would have been. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, I was initializing the Aws config hash (outside the paperclip config object because i have other uses for the API) with the bucket name inside and it seems that it does not like it too much. I move the bucket name into the papeclip defaults object and it worked! something like this.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

Looking at the configuration options on the documentation it says:

> You can configure default credentials and region via Aws.config. In
>   version 2, Aws.config is a vanilla Ruby hash, not a method like it was
>   in version 1. The Aws.config hash takes precedence over environment
>   variables.
>
> require 'aws-sdk'
>
> Aws.config.update({   region: 'us-west-2',   credentials:
>   Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret') })

This is the basic configuration and there are other options you can lookup here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/#Configuration_Options

One little advice i could give here is to be careful to which version of the SDK you are using to read the right docs. Not so long ago the version 3 came out and there was a mix in the results on the topic i was looking for.